# Photos downloaded from facebook are appearing in Google Photos

Tags: facebook, samsung-galaxy-note-3, google-photos

Photos I download with the Facebook app on my Samsung Galaxy Note 3 are synced to Google Photos. I would like only photos I take with my phone's camera or add manually to appear in Google Photos. Is this possible? How?

No folders are selected in the "Choose folders to back up..." dialogue.

Comment: Have you turned on Auto-sync of your Google photos. It will backup the photos in your phone automatically if you set to sync automatically.

Comment: In the Photos app, Settings -> Backup & sync -> Backup is set to on. Camera photos are beeing synced, along with unwanted photos from Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

there is a simple solution to hide facebook downloaded pictures from google photo or the stock galery or technically speaking hide them from the android media scanner.

1. locate where the photos are downloaded facebook download to your external storage `/DCIM/facebook` and the facebook messenger app store it's pictures under `/pictures/messenger`
2. use a file manager app like [es file explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop) navigate to the location of the pictures and create a new file name it `.nomedia`
3. it's done the pictures downloaded from facebook will not show in the google photo.

Comment: .nomedia will hide the pictures from all image viewing apps, so this is not a solution.

Comment: sorry that's all I got for you because facebook puts it's photos under /DCIM and google photos sync /DCIM  if you can change the location where facebook app store the downloaded pictures elsewhere you will fix this problem

Answer (score 0):

As written by me [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/170775/194952):

I had EXACTLY the same problem. I couldn't find a solution else where. The only solution was to use a .nomedia file in the `/sdcard/DCIM/Facebook` directory and moving the *.jpgs to another folder. I had made a Tasker task referring to a reddit post in [/r/tasker](http://reddit.com/r/). Here is the description and the XML for importing it. You have to create the `%destpart` and add a `.nomedia` in `%sourcepath` for it to work. You can run this task in a profile as an exit task for Facebook and as an entry task for other messenger apps like Telegram/Whatsapp, etc. so you get your memes right!

```
The Meme Mover (3)
A1: Variable Set [ Name:%sourcepath To:/sdcard/DCIM/Facebook/ Recurse Variables:Off Do Maths:Off Append:Off ] 
A2: Variable Set [ Name:%destpath To:/sdcard/Pictures/Facebook/ Recurse Variables:Off Do Maths:Off Append:Off ] 
A3: Variable Set [ Name:%suffix To:(1) Recurse Variables:Off Do Maths:Off Append:Off ] 
A4: Variable Set [ Name:%counter To:0 Recurse Variables:Off Do Maths:On Append:Off ] 
A5: List Files [ Dir:%sourcepath Match:*.jpg/*.png/*.jpeg/*.gif/*.3gp Include Hidden Files:Off Use Root:Off Sort Select:Alphabetic Variable:%filestomove ] 
A6: For [ Variable:%thispathfile Items:%filestomove() ] 
A7: Variable Split [ Name:%thispathfile Splitter:/ Delete Base:Off ] 
A8: Variable Set [ Name:%len To:%thispathfile(#) Recurse Variables:Off Do Maths:Off Append:Off ] 
A9: Variable Set [ Name:%filename To:%thispathfile(%len) Recurse Variables:Off Do Maths:Off Append:Off ] 
A10: Variable Clear [ Name:%exists Pattern Matching:Off ] 
A11: Test File [ Type:Type Data:%destpath%filename Store Result In:%exists Use Root:Off Continue Task After Error:On ] 
A12: If [ %exists !Set ]
A13: Move [ From:%thispathfile To:%destpath%filename Use Root:Off ] 
A14: Scan Card [ File:%destpath%filename ] 
A15: Else 
A16: Variable Split [ Name:%filename Splitter:. Delete Base:Off ] 
A17: Variable Set [ Name:%filename1 To:%filename1%suffix Recurse Variables:Off Do Maths:Off Append:Off ] 
A18: Variable Join [ Name:%filename Joiner:. Delete Parts:Off ] 
A19: Move [ From:%thispathfile To:%destpath%filename Use Root:Off ] 
A20: Scan Card [ File:%destpath%filename ] 
A21: End If 
A22: Variable Add [ Name:%counter Value:1 Wrap Around:0 ] 
A23: End For 
A24: If [ %counter eq 0 ]
A25: [X] Flash [ Text:No memes? Sad. Long:On ] 
A26: Else If [ %counter eq 1 ]
A27: Flash [ Text:%counter meme moved! Long:On ] 
A28: Else 
A29: Flash [ Text:%counter memes moved! Long:On ]
```

**Remember to have .nomedia in %sourcepath**

Here's the XML for direct import:

```
<TaskerData sr="" dvi="1" tv="4.9u4">
<Task sr="task3">
    <cdate>1489093858387</cdate>
    <edate>1489219027762</edate>
    <id>3</id>
    <nme>The Meme Mover</nme>
    <pri>100</pri>
    <Kid sr="Kid">
        <launchID>3</launchID>
        <pkg>me.regalstreak.movefb</pkg>
        <vnme>1.0</vnme>
    </Kid>
    <Action sr="act0" ve="7">
        <code>547</code>
        <Str sr="arg0" ve="3">%sourcepath</Str>
        <Str sr="arg1" ve="3">/sdcard/DCIM/Facebook/</Str>
        <Int sr="arg2" val="0"/>
        <Int sr="arg3" val="0"/>
        <Int sr="arg4" val="0"/>
    </Action>
    <Action sr="act1" ve="7">
        <code>547</code>
        <Str sr="arg0" ve="3">%destpath</Str>
        <Str sr="arg1" ve="3">/sdcard/Pictures/Facebook/</Str>
        <Int sr="arg2" val="0"/>
        <Int sr="arg3" val="0"/>
        <Int sr="arg4" val="0"/>
    </Action>
    <Action sr="act10" ve="7">
        <code>342</code>
        <se>false</se>
        <Int sr="arg0" val="4"/>
        <Str sr="arg1" ve="3">%destpath%filename</Str>
        <Str sr="arg2" ve="3">%exists</Str>
        <Int sr="arg3" val="0"/>
    </Action>
    <Action sr="act11" ve="7">
        <code>37</code>
        <ConditionList sr="if">
            <Condition sr="c0" ve="3">
                <lhs>%exists</lhs>
                <op>13</op>
                <rhs></rhs>
            </Condition>
        </ConditionList>
    </Action>
    <Action sr="act12" ve="7">
        <code>400</code>
        <Str sr="arg0" ve="3">%thispathfile</Str>
        <Str sr="arg1" ve="3">%destpath%filename</Str>
        <Int sr="arg2" val="0"/>
    </Action>
    <Action sr="act13" ve="7">
        <code>459</code>
        <Str sr="arg0" ve="3">%destpath%filename</Str>
    </Action>
    <Action sr="act14" ve="7">
        <code>43</code>
    </Action>
    <Action sr="act15" ve="7">
        <code>590</code>
        <Str sr="arg0" ve="3">%filename</Str>
        <Str sr="arg1" ve="3">.</Str>
        <Int sr="arg2" val="0"/>
    </Action>
    <Action sr="act16" ve="7">
        <code>547</code>
        <Str sr="arg0" ve="3">%filename1</Str>
        <Str sr="arg1" ve="3">%filename1%suffix</Str>
        <Int sr="arg2" val="0"/>
        <Int sr="arg3" val="0"/>
        <Int sr="arg4" val="0"/>
    </Action>
    <Action sr="act17" ve="7">
        <code>592</code>
        <Str sr="arg0" ve="3">%filename</Str>
        <Str sr="arg1" ve="3">.</Str>
        <Int sr="arg2" val="0"/>
    </Action>
    <Action sr="act18" ve="7">
        <code>400</code>
        <Str sr="arg0" ve="3">%thispathfile</Str>
        <Str sr="arg1" ve="3">%destpath%filename</Str>
        <Int sr="arg2" val="0"/>
    </Action>
    <Action sr="act19" ve="7">
        <code>459</code>
        <Str sr="arg0" ve="3">%destpath%filename</Str>
    </Action>
    <Action sr="act2" ve="7">
        <code>547</code>
        <Str sr="arg0" ve="3">%suffix</Str>
        <Str sr="arg1" ve="3">(1)</Str>
        <Int sr="arg2" val="0"/>
        <Int sr="arg3" val="0"/>
        <Int sr="arg4" val="0"/>
    </Action>
    <Action sr="act20" ve="7">
        <code>38</code>
    </Action>
    <Action sr="act21" ve="7">
        <code>888</code>
        <Str sr="arg0" ve="3">%counter</Str>
        <Int sr="arg1" val="1"/>
        <Int sr="arg2" val="0"/>
    </Action>
    <Action sr="act22" ve="7">
        <code>40</code>
    </Action>
    <Action sr="act23" ve="7">
        <code>37</code>
        <ConditionList sr="if">
            <Condition sr="c0" ve="3">
                <lhs>%counter</lhs>
                <op>0</op>
                <rhs>0</rhs>
            </Condition>
        </ConditionList>
    </Action>
    <Action sr="act24" ve="7">
        <code>548</code>
        <on>false</on>
        <Str sr="arg0" ve="3">No memes? Sad.</Str>
        <Int sr="arg1" val="1"/>
    </Action>
    <Action sr="act25" ve="7">
        <code>43</code>
        <ConditionList sr="if">
            <Condition sr="c0" ve="3">
                <lhs>%counter</lhs>
                <op>0</op>
                <rhs>1</rhs>
            </Condition>
        </ConditionList>
    </Action>
    <Action sr="act26" ve="7">
        <code>548</code>
        <Str sr="arg0" ve="3">%counter meme moved!</Str>
        <Int sr="arg1" val="1"/>
    </Action>
    <Action sr="act27" ve="7">
        <code>43</code>
    </Action>
    <Action sr="act28" ve="7">
        <code>548</code>
        <Str sr="arg0" ve="3">%counter memes moved!</Str>
        <Int sr="arg1" val="1"/>
    </Action>
    <Action sr="act3" ve="7">
        <code>547</code>
        <Str sr="arg0" ve="3">%counter</Str>
        <Str sr="arg1" ve="3">0</Str>
        <Int sr="arg2" val="0"/>
        <Int sr="arg3" val="1"/>
        <Int sr="arg4" val="0"/>
    </Action>
    <Action sr="act4" ve="7">
        <code>412</code>
        <Str sr="arg0" ve="3">%sourcepath</Str>
        <Str sr="arg1" ve="3">*.jpg/*.png/*.jpeg/*.gif/*.3gp</Str>
        <Int sr="arg2" val="0"/>
        <Int sr="arg3" val="0"/>
        <Int sr="arg4" val="0"/>
        <Str sr="arg5" ve="3">%filestomove</Str>
    </Action>
    <Action sr="act5" ve="7">
        <code>39</code>
        <Str sr="arg0" ve="3">%thispathfile</Str>
        <Str sr="arg1" ve="3">%filestomove()</Str>
    </Action>
    <Action sr="act6" ve="7">
        <code>590</code>
        <Str sr="arg0" ve="3">%thispathfile</Str>
        <Str sr="arg1" ve="3">/</Str>
        <Int sr="arg2" val="0"/>
    </Action>
    <Action sr="act7" ve="7">
        <code>547</code>
        <Str sr="arg0" ve="3">%len</Str>
        <Str sr="arg1" ve="3">%thispathfile(#)</Str>
        <Int sr="arg2" val="0"/>
        <Int sr="arg3" val="0"/>
        <Int sr="arg4" val="0"/>
    </Action>
    <Action sr="act8" ve="7">
        <code>547</code>
        <Str sr="arg0" ve="3">%filename</Str>
        <Str sr="arg1" ve="3">%thispathfile(%len)</Str>
        <Int sr="arg2" val="0"/>
        <Int sr="arg3" val="0"/>
        <Int sr="arg4" val="0"/>
    </Action>
    <Action sr="act9" ve="7">
        <code>549</code>
        <Str sr="arg0" ve="3">%exists</Str>
        <Int sr="arg1" val="0"/>
    </Action>
    <Img sr="icn" ve="2">
        <cls>com.facebook.katana.LoginActivity</cls>
        <pkg>com.facebook.katana</pkg>
    </Img>
</Task>
```

Pro Tip: Enable A25 just for testing if you want to.

Edit: Code corrected and updated. (1 memes moved was triggering my OCD.)

Edit 2: Had some problems, corrected again.